# Rails + aws-sk + S3 Object metadata multiple update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm currently trying to work out the best way to update multiple S3 Objects MetaData within a single form.

Has anyone done this before or have any suggestions on how I could accomplish this?

I upload the files manually but wish to update some metadata i add when I upload manually. e.g. x-amz-meta-friendly-title, x-amz-meta-description, x-amz-meta-active

Any guidance is much appreciated.